# Codeigniter session nagios

Tags: codeigniter, session, nagios

I'm using the session library that comes with CodeIgniter but I got a slight problem with it. I'm using a database to store all sessions but the session library also stores some strange rows with user_agent = 'check_http/v1.4.14 (nagios-plugins 1.4.14)'. My application is uploaded to a server with ssh. These kind of rows are added to the database almost every other second so the number of rows gets huge. I´ve read about Nagios but do anyone know how I can prevent these rows from being added to the database without changing in the session library?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a -**strange**- row. **Codeigniter Session library** stores an userdata for each Session, and It's clearly defined in the class: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_cookie.php#L495

Now, If you want you can handle userdatas and which one is stored in database which one is not. Check out the "userdata" array.

Comment: Yes I know it does that but I don´t want to save sessions for nagios. Can I handle "userdata" in some smart way without configure the session file?

Comment: Yes you can. In the controller you can set **$this->session->unset_userdata('user_agent');** like this.

Comment: That gave me an error in my session class. But if I use that I have to do something like

if ($this->session->userdata('user_agent') == check_http/v1.4.14 (nagios-plugins 1.4.14)) $this->session->unset_userdata('user_agent');

in every controller and that seems not right...
Nagios got user_agent = 'check_http/v1.4.14 (nagios-plugins 1.4.14)' and I don´t want the session library to save any row that belongs to  Nagios.

Comment: You can extend your CI_Controller as MY_Controller in core/ folder. And add a check control to construct function. Or you can do it in CI_Controller directly.

Comment: I´ve tried that but it still uploads a row to the database and I get an error because of unsetting 'user_agent'. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: I dont think it is a good idea to solve this problem out of Session Library. Alternatively you can write a class that extends Codeigniter Session Class and you can overwrite sess_create() function to do this condition. Then you should load your new Session Class not Codeigniter Session Class.

Comment: Yes I think that´s the best way to solve my problem. Thanks for all you help!